# The program 'show' is currently not installed.

Tags: command-line, system-installation

I keep getting this error message: "The program 'show' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install nmh"

I already did what the prompt says. I try to run a show command and gives me the same error. Any recommendations?

Comment: The package `nmh` provides `/usr/bin/mh/show` http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nmh → http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/nmh/filelist